# Is ApplicationContext.xml necessary in a SpringBoot project to call an external jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-management

Sorry if my question seems simple for you, but if I usually create a lot of spring boot projects, it's the first time someone ask me to integrate inside a dependancy from another project.

He asked me to create an ApplicationContext.xml with a spring-datasource-config.xml and also a spring-hibernate-config.xml.

Is it the only solution, or can I do the same with application.properties ?

Collaboration is very important and I suppose I'm too much "modern" where my mate is too much "old school". I would like to adapt myself but it's very complicated to get informations...

Thanks to the community for your help!

Comment: That depends on a jar. But simplest way would be to do it as your colleague says

Comment: Yes, I think you're true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect two worlds togheter, you can import those files from inside of `@Configuration` class with [`@ImportResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html)

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("spring-datasource-config.xml", "spring-hibernate-config.xml")
class MyConfig {}
```

Comment: Actually, and don't ask me how, I am able to put an @Autowired on a DAO, on with the applicationContext and the config.xml files. I don't declare them anywhere and it seems to work like that... ^^'